# Is there any way to set kerning to SKLabelNode for iOS 10 and newer?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'd like to set some kerning to `SKLabelNode`. I used `NSAttributedString` and this solution working fine on iOS 11 or newer.

But I need to support iOS 10 too. Is there any way to set kerning that support iOS 10 and newer?

```swift
class Caption: SKLabelNode {

    static func addNode(at position: CGPoint, isBold: Bool, text: String) -> Caption {

        let font = isBold ? "Roboto-Bold" : "Roboto-Regular"

        let attr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont(name: font, size: 16)!,
            .foregroundColor: SKColor.white,
            .kern: 2.0
        ]

        let caption = Caption(attributedText: NSAttributedString(string: text.uppercased(), attributes: attr))
        caption.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
        caption.verticalAlignmentMode = .top
        caption.position = position   
        return caption
    }
}
```

Xcode says: `'init(attributedText:)' is only available on iOS 11 or newer.`

```swift
let caption = Caption(attributedText: NSAttributedString(string: text.uppercased(), attributes: attr))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  You are going to have to come up with a different method like render with a UILabel, extract a UIImage out of it, use the UIImage on an SKSpriteNode.

Of course, the most simple solution is to just abandon iOS 10 support  (something like 5% of iOS users are on iOS 10)